# Newly Created Domain Admin has Less Permissions

Tags: windows-7, permissions, domain

I created a new user on the Domain controller of a test lab I have running in VMware, and added that user to the Domain Admins group. Upon actually using the account I noticed that it had significantly less permissions then the original domain administrator. I tried adding the user to the Enterprise Admins and Schema Admins as well, but it didn't change anything. The new Domain Admin's permissions seem to be the same as a Domain User. As far as I can tell I can only run net view as well as mount a share and a few other small things. I get Permissioned Denied with just about everything else.

> net user NewAdmin /domain

```
Local Group Memberships     *Administrators
Global Group Memberships    *Domain Users      *Enterprise Admins
                            *Schema Admins     *Domain Admins
```

Why does the new domain admin have such restrictions? Is there a way to create a new domain admin with the same level of authority as the original? This is how I created the user in the first place.

> net user Name Pass /add /domain
>
> net group "Domain Admins" Name /add /domain

Answer (score 1):

> Why does the new domain admin have such restrictions?

There's no reason I can think of that that this should be happening, at least nothing by default.

> Is there a way to create a new domain admin with the same level of authority as the original?

If you want to make another user based on an existing one in ADU&C, right-click the user you want to copy and click "*Copy...*".

Comment: I haven't changed any settings that would do that as far as I know. I edited the OP with the method I used to create the user.

Comment: Ok, I recreated the user and it seems that the user does have more privileges then domain users(can mount ADMIN$ shares). But the original Domain Admin still has more privileges on the local machines. For example, the original Admin can create and delete users on local machines, but the new one cannot.